# Azure Arm template deployment of a web app zip package programmatically using build artifact

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

**Short question:**

I was wondering if packageUri parameter in MSDeploy resource (Deploy azure app service) below can point to the location of VSTS build Server drop location that is used by Release pipeline.

**How to programmatically get acccess to build drop location?**
To use vsts api? Which ones?
Maybe this link can shed some lights:

[understanding artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts#download)

[grab-your-build-artifacts-from-visual-studio-online](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2014/09/12/quick-easy-steps-to-grab-your-build-artifacts-from-visual-studio-online/)

[Basic authentication for the REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth)

```js
"resources": [
  {
    "name": "MSDeploy",
    "type": "extensions",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
      "displayName": "ContentDeploy"
    },
    "properties": {
      "packageUri": "[concat(parameters('packageUrl'), parameters('sasToken'))]",
      "dbType": "None",
      "connectionString": "",
      "setParameters": {
          "IIS Web Application Name": "[parameters('siteName')]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Longer question and explanation:**
I am using VSTS release definition to deploy my web app infrastructure during development.
The web app will be build and packaged by my VSTS build and uploaded to Server drop location. I am using on-premise (my PC) agent for both my build and release pipeline.

While I can do web app deployments using vsts Deploy Azure App Service release task (that knows how to find build artifacts), I want to do an automated deployment of multiple web app programmatically from a web app I intend to build.

I want to know if this .zip web app package can be somehow made available to my ARM deployment template. Everybody recommends copying .zip package to a storage blob with SAS token and that way Release "Deploy azure app service" can find it. 
I want to avoid this copying. Actually I want at least to programmatically download this package and eventually copy it it a storage blob container if I cannot manage to do it as asked.

Here is my little research I did:

I turned on agent logging for both build and release

```js
Some Build variables:
BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY=F:\agent\_work\1\s
BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY=F:\agent\_work\1\a


Some release variables:
[SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY] --> [F:\agent\_work\r3\a]
[RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_ECOMMERCESITECI_SOURCEVERSION] --> [91]
[BUILD_BUILDNUMBER] --> [20161230.12]
[BUILD_BUILDID] --> [85]
[SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID] --> [7ab6c2a4-208d-411d-81e5-5e88b26f2252]
[RELEASE_RELEASEWEBURL] --> [https://vstsaccount.visualstudio.com/7ab6c2a4-208d-411d-81e5-5e88b26f2252/_apps/hub/ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.hub-explorer?releaseId=103&_a=release-summary]
```

RELEASE_RELEASEWEBURL is an interesting page where I can press Artifacts which show all linked sources (in my case I have one Primary source coming from my CI build.). I can then follow the link and reach a specific build EcommerceSiteCI / Build 20161230.12 and I can press download button (from the link below) to download .zip package which I am after. I would like to find out about it but programmatically from my Arm template. I would like to create a Web app or Api app that can programmatically discover this .zip package and using it to deploy the app using "Web Deploy for Web Apps" resource.

https://vstsaccount.visualstudio.com/vstsproject/_build/index?buildId=85&_a=summary&tab=artifacts

Looking at fiddler I managed to see what is the url of asset download:

GET https://vstsaccount.visualstudio.com/7ab6c2a4-208d-411d-81e5-5e88b26f2252/_apis/build/builds/85/artifacts?artifactName=drop&%24format=zip

So I can see based on [BUILD_BUILDID] --> [85] and [SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID] --> [7ab6c2a4-208d-411d-81e5-5e88b26f2252] I can assemble this URL.
The only thing is how to authenticate this request. When I entered above address I was prompted to sign in using Microsoft account and I saw it is oauth 2.0 authentication. The url is something like this:
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_type=code&client_id=51483342-012c-4d86-bf138-cf50c7252078&scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access&response_mode=form_pos
etc...(some encrypted string - probably representing .zip package location is omitted).

Even if I cannot make this download url available to MSDeploy arm resource
it would be great if I could programmatically download it and upload to a Storage blob container and generate SAS token for MSDeploy to find it.

So how to programmatically get acccess to build drop location?
Thanks
Rad

Comment: pretty sure you just need to provide a bearer token using "Authentication" header

Comment: This should be a non-interactive user. As I said above I need to know how to retrieve the latest or specific artifact .zip package behind a web app or a web job  and start a deploy of PaaS infrastructure as a code and MS deploy using Template and Parameter like:   ResourceManagementClient client = new ResourceManagementClient( new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, token););
client.Deployments.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, correlationId.ToString(), new DeploymentProperties(Mode, Template, Parameters...etc)); Is there a way to use something like Persona Access Token for VSTS Build APIs.

Comment: I just found out how to obtain a token, but in the example where I found the code below they create new TokenCredentials out of this token, while I need TokenCloudCredentials instance. I don't know what is the difference between the two. var cc = new ClientCredential("{client-id}", "{client-secret}");
   var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenant-id}");
   var token = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc); Let's say that I found a way to interact with vsts api from a service,how to obtain .zip artifact coming from a certain build

Comment: Did you figure out your issue? I'm encountering the same problems, and wanted to see if there was someone else that figured this out first.

Answer (score 0):

I recently blogged about using PowerShell to queue a build and pull the artifacts using the the TFS API.  Works great for us.

```
$artifacts = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Credential $creds -ContentType application/json -Uri "$TFSUri/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/artifacts?api-version=2.0"
foreach($artifact in $artifacts.value)
{
    $filePath = $artifact.resource.downloadUrl.Replace("file:", "").Replace("/", "\").Replace("%20", " ");          
    $path  = $filePath + "\*Package\*"
    if (Test-Path $path)
    {        
        $packagePath = "MSDeployPackages\$project-$buildName\"; 
        if ((Test-Path $packagePath) -eq $false) {
            New-Item $packagePath -ItemType directory
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $packagePath -Recurse -Force
    }
}
```

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/10/14/queue-tfsvsts-builds-via-powershell/